# Symfony - addHaving - concat + regexp

Tags: regex, doctrine-orm, concatenation, query-builder, doctrine-dbal

Raw query:

```
select firstfield, secondfield, phone_number, thirdfield 
from table 
having CONCAT(firstfield, ' ', secondfield, ' ', thirdfield, ' ', fourthfield) regexp 'value' 
   and CONCAT(firstfield, ' ', secondfield, ' ', thirdfield, ' ', fourthfield) regexp 'value2' 
   and CONCAT(firstfield, ' ', secondfield, ' ', thirdfield, ' ', fourthfield) regexp 'value3'
   and CONCAT(firstfield, ' ', secondfield, ' ', thirdfield, ' ', fourthfield) regexp 'value4'
```

Querybuilder

```
    $qb->select(
        'firstfield',
    'secondfield',
    'thirdfield',
    'fourthfield',
    )->from(Table, 'u');


$queryHaving = "CONCAT(firstfield, ' ', secondfield, ' ', thirdfield, ' ', fourthfield) regexp 'value'";
$qb->andhaving($queryHaving);

$queryHaving = "CONCAT(firstfield, ' ', secondfield, ' ', thirdfield, ' ', fourthfield) regexp 'value2'";
$qb->andhaving($queryHaving);
```

Problem:

How to collect concat with regexp not as function? Tried using literal() function but it is not possible to create due error throws on not possible to assign into.

Comment: which database will you run the query at?

Comment: Oracle MySQL doctrine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query seems to work for me for MySQL with any of these 2 forms:

```
select *
from test
having concat(field1, field2) regexp '^[FB].*' and
       concat(field1, field2) regexp 'o$';

select *
from test
where concat(field1, field2) regexp '^[FB].*' and
      concat(field1, field2) regexp 'o$';
```

See demo **[here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/voDm4dBcskovYjkKCxeNfa/0)**

I'm just thinkging about the problem could be with CHAR columns

So, for example, one column would have `FOO<space><space>` on a `CHAR(5)` instead of `FOO` at `VARCHAR(5)`. So when concatenating you would have something similar to `FOO<space><space>BAR<space><space>` and thus the regex would fail.

However, with SQLFiddle it doesn't seem to be the case. It does not seem to add spaces. See **[here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/w9YejUGRSPMfMkJWaDcjTd/0)**.

Anyways, it may be worth trying on your app: Are you using chars or varchars? Could you try adding `trims` at the columns, like this:

```
select *,concat(trim(field1), trim(field2))
from test
having concat(trim(field1), trim(field2)) regexp '^[FB].*' and
       concat(trim(field1), trim(field2)) regexp 'o$';


select *,concat(trim(field1), trim(field2))
from test
where concat(trim(field1), trim(field2)) regexp '^[FB].*' and
      concat(trim(field1), trim(field2)) regexp 'o$';
```

Demo **[here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tunTKHcgEvC4eMUAgY6czA/0)**.

Comment: No, there are on Symfony a command ->concat. How to use in querybuilder?

Comment: Perhaps you could use something like this: `$queryHaving = "CONCAT(trim(firstfield), ' ', trim(secondfield), ' ', trim(thirdfield), ' ', trim(fourthfield)) regexp 'value'";`

Comment: Yes, but you should put literal() var in querybuilder. In these scenario with literatal due we have "concat(...) regexp <regex>" and putting into having into query builder throws errors like you can't these combine with outside of regexp.

I will mark you as resolved due no one has answer or none found using literal + querybilder + having